# Use of except in the sentence

Tags: word-usage, british-english, except

Yeah! I love animals except cats .
Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest that you seek answers to this question on ELL and not on ELU.

And secondly, I'd rephrase the sentence as:

> Yeah! I love all animals except cats.

Notice that I've added *all* to the sentence.

You could also say:

> Yeah! I love all animals but cats.

The latter is much more pertinent in instances wherein the subject prevailing talks particularly about cats.